# How can I get TextField input by using ArrayList

Tags: java, javafx, junit

I need to test a method that takes an input TextFild, how can I change the input to  ArrayList to get the data. I am getting an error that says

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Character cannot be cast to class

```
    private boolean validatePassword() {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,15})");
            Matcher matcher = p.matcher(passwordField.getText());
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                return true;

            } else {
                lblMessage.setText("Please enter a valid password \n" +
                        "(at least one uppercase, lowercase and 8 or more characters ");
                return false;

            }
        }
```

my solution

```
    public class TestCases {
        ArrayList<Character> characters = new ArrayList<>();

        public boolean validatePassword() {

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,15})");
            for (int i = 0; i < characters.size(); i++) {
                Object j = characters.get(i);
                Matcher matcher = p.matcher((CharSequence) j);
                if (matcher.matches()) {
                    return true;

                } else {
                    System.out.println(
                            "Please enter a valid password \n" +
                            "(at least one uppercase, lowercase and 8 or more characters "););
                    return false;

                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        public void setEmail(ArrayList<Character> list) {
            characters = list;
        }

    }
```

Junit class

```
    @Test
    void test() {
        String password= "Kd123456";
        ArrayList<Character> paswordField=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i= 0 ; i<password.length(); i++){
            paswordField.add(password.charAt(i));
        }

        TestCases valid= new TestCases();
        valid.setEmail(paswordField);
        assertEquals(true,valid.validatePassword());
    }

}
```

Comment: You get the class cast exception because a `Character` is not a `CharSequence`, so `(CharSequence) j` fails. It's not really clear what you're trying to do here; you appear to be trying to test if any individual character in the list of characters matches the regular expression, which is of course impossible.

Comment: @James_D is there any other way that I check the input if it matches with validPasswod pattern

Comment: Why are you using an `ArrayList<Character>` in the first place? Why not just use a `String`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if hope this will help you !!

```
 import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TestCases {

    public boolean validatePassword(String s) {

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-z0-9 ]).{8,15})",
                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(s);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            return true;

        } else {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid password \n"
                    + "(at least one uppercase, lowercase and 8 or more characters ");
            return false;

        }

    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        String password = "Kd12@3456";

        TestCases valid = new TestCases();

        assertEquals(true, valid.validatePassword(password));
    }

}
```

Comment: Run the above program and check if you are able to check the password , please accept the answer and vote up !!

Comment: your I die helped me, can you change this way in order to match

Comment: public class TestCases {
   String characters= "";
    public boolean validatePassword() {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,15})");
            Matcher matcher = p.matcher(characters);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                return true;

            } else {
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid password (at least one uppercase, lowercase and 8 or more characters ");
                return false;
            }
    }
    public void setEmail(String str){
        this.characters=str;
    }
}

Comment: class TestCasesTest {


    @Test
    void validatePassword() {

        String password= "KK1234567";
        ArrayList<Character> paswordField=new ArrayList<>();
        //for(int i= 0 ; i<password.length(); i++){
       //     paswordField.add(password.charAt(i));
    //    }
        TestCases valid= new TestCases();
        valid.setEmail(password);
        assertEquals(true,valid.validatePassword() );
    }
}

Comment: You should not be focusing on the way but on the logic that's it